# Bootstrap checkboxes acting weird on different browsers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple website with pure HTML, CSS, PHP and Bootstrap. I want to use the checkboxes from Bootstrap, but they seem to be acting weird in different browsers... For example in Chrome, they are really big and out of place.
[image: Checkboxes]

And on Safari, they appear normal, but when clicked on, they do a jumping motion..

I want them to appear normal size and all on the same line.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Products :</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline checkbox-list">
              <li><label class="checkbox-inline">Food </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="products[]" value="food">
              </li>
              <li><label class="checkbox-inline">Books</label><br>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="products[]" value="books">
              </li>
              <li><label class="checkbox-inline">Phones</label><br>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="products[]" value="phones">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Show some CSS so it can be checked, but before anything give your checkboxes their own unique id. I'm not to sure about `name`'s with brackets either...

Comment: Most of it is from Bootstrap. The rest either doesn't have css linked to it or the css is commented...